# Specific Crosstab

Tags: sql, postgresql, crosstab, postgres-crosstab

I'm facing a problem with some data, so i need to use a crosstab to generate a specific report, could you help me?

Basicaly i have one query select like this:
select route_id,id,tipo,local,valor_cobrado from itinerario

and inside this table i have this data below:
[image]

As you can see we have sometimes Coleta and Entrega with the same route_id, so i need to have someting like that:

```
route_id | id | tipo Coleta | local Coleta | tipo Entrega | local Entrega | sum(valor_cobrado)
```

Is it possible?
thank you!

Comment: It smell likes a simple aggregation, but to be sure please share the exact expected result.

Comment: Thank you for your help, Jim!
I need to have a result like that using rows 14 and 15 in my print above:

12 | Coleta | DDTI | Entrega | Vogler Industria e Comércio Ltda | 888.40 |